# Date functions in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have teradata scripts

```
AND ADD_MONTHS('?StartDate',1)-1 BETWEEN A.CNTSTRT_DT AND COALESCE(A.CNTEND_DT, DATE)
```

This script looks like it prompts for a date, then adds one month to that date. But I'm not clear on what the -1 does.

Additionally, I see that it compares the date to see if they are between the CNTSTRT_DT and CNTEND_DT, but what does the DATE do specifically?

Comment: it's whatever teradata does when you take a date (the result of add_months) and subtract integer 1 from it. e.g. maybe it subtracts a day, or an hour, or a minute, or a second...

Comment: so are you saying that it adds 1 month, but then subtracts 1 day? Sorry, I guess I'm still not understanding.

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS('?StartDate',1)-1` = *Add one month to the prompted date and subtract one day, `DATE` is old Teradata syntax for Standard SQL  `CURRENT_DATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -1 is to substruct one day, for example the query:

```
select ADD_MONTHS(cast('2016/01/25' as date),1)-1
```

returns: 24/02/2016

Also, "Date" is a function which returns current date.